# collect2 error while building linphone-android

Tags: android, ubuntu, linphone

I tried to build linphone-android on MasOS and Linux Ubuntu, but Both times I encountered the same error. There are multiple threads on this error, but no solution yet. Hopefully, some of you could give me an advice. Here is the error:

```
    ...
/home/romans/Development/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencoreamr.a(wrapper.o): in function Encoder_Interface_Encode:jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:66: error: undefined reference to 'my_AMREncode'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/romans/Development/linphone/linphone-android'
make: *** [generate-libs] Error 2
```